# Php sum array std class object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have print_r array like this. How do I SUM field 'credit' ?

[image]

I want to result like this in html :

1. 650000
2. 500000
3. 500000
4. 500000
5. 200000

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code, data or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Answer (score 3):

you can create funtion to sum your array

```
function sum_credit($array){
  $sum = 0;
  foreach($array as $val){
    $sum += $val->credit;
  }
  return $sum;
}
```

and print your data with

```
echo sum_credit($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$creditSum = array_sum(array_column($array,'credit'));
```

With array_column, a one-dimensional array is created from 'credit' values and then the sum is calculated with array_sum.